# Getting PNG/JPG image from reddit API

Tags: javascript, reddit

I use this program. I usually use `"https://i.ibb.co/CBsYJYn/image.jpg"`. This app must require a lot of photos to be rendered, so I want to use the API of reddit. But I'm confused about how to get PNG images from reddit via the API.

```
const menupict = [
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json",
]
const pictrand = menupict[Math.floor(Math.random() * (menupict.length))]
await client.sendFileFromUrl(from, pictrand, 'gambar.jpg')
break
```

Comment: You need to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the URL first and parse it as JSON. Only then can you randomly pick one of the images. `fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json").then(r => r.json()).then(({ data }) => { ... });` However that resource isn't CORS enabled so you cannot fetch it from in-browser JS.

Comment: so the probability that it is not drawn at random?

Comment: It looks like the JSON is randomly selecting 25 memes. Not sure what you're asking though.

Comment: @dinidimatio can you please try to elaborate what you are trying to achieve?
maybe draw a mockup ? (draw.io)

Comment: here I want to shuffle some memes to change to jpg and png output variables

Comment: the point is, how to make an api from reddit "https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json" to png